# Efficiency of flattening and collecting slices

Tags: rust, iterator, slice, flatten, memory-efficient

If one uses the standard `.flatten().collect::<Box<[T]>>()` on an `Iterator<Item=&[T]> where T: Copy`, does it:

- perform a single allocation; and
- use `memcpy` to copy each item to the destination

or does it do something less efficient?

Comment: Do you mean `.flatten().copied().collect::<Box<[T]>>()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Box<[T]>` does not implement `FromIterator<&T>`, so I'll assume your actual inner iterator is something that yields owned `T`s.

`FromIterator<T>` for `Box<[T]>` [forwards to](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/boxed.rs.html#812-816) `Vec<T>`, which [uses `size_hint()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/vec.rs.html#1921) to reserve space for `lower` + 1 items, and reallocates as it grows beyond that (moving elements as necessary). So the question is, what does `Flatten<I>` return for `size_hint`?

The implementation of `Iterator::size_hint` for `Flatten<I>` [forwards to the internal struct `FlattenCompat<I>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/iter/adapters/flatten.rs.html#155), which is a little complicated because it supports double-ended iteration, but ultimately [returns `(0, None)` if the outer iterator has not been advanced or exhausted](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/iter/adapters/flatten.rs.html#245).

So the answer to your question is: it does something less efficient. Namely, (unless you have already called `next` or `next_back` on the iterator at least once) it creates an empty `Vec<T>` and grows it progressively according to whatever growth strategy `Vec` uses (which is unspecified, but [guaranteed by the documentation to result in `O(1)` amortized `push`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html)).

This isn't an artificial limitation; it is fundamental to the way `Flatten` works. The only way you could pre-calculate the size of the flattened iterator is by exhausting the outer iterator and adding up all the inner `size_hint`s. This is a bad idea both because it doesn't always work (the inner iterators may not return useful `size_hint`s) and because you also have to find a way to keep the inner iterators around after exhausting the outer one; there's no solution that would be acceptable for a general purpose iterator adapter.

If you know something about your particular iterator that enables you to know what the final size should be, you can reserve the allocation yourself by calling `Vec::with_capacity` and use [`Extend`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Extend.html#tymethod.extend) to fill it from the `flatten`ed iterator, rather than using `collect`.

Comment: Awesome answer!  I was already doing exactly what you suggested in your final para, but on review wondered whether flattening and collecting would be a more eloquent way of achieving the same; alas, I shall leave as-is.  Thank you.