# Does Iterator::collect allocate the same amount of memory as String::with_capacity?

Tags: rust, dynamic-memory-allocation

In C++ when joining a bunch of strings (where each element's size is known roughly), it's common to pre-allocate memory to avoid multiple re-allocations and moves:

```cpp
std::vector<std::string> words;
constexpr size_t APPROX_SIZE = 20;

std::string phrase;
phrase.reserve((words.size() + 5) * APPROX_SIZE);  // <-- avoid multiple allocations
for (const auto &w : words)
  phrase.append(w);
```

Similarly, I did this in Rust (this chunk needs the [unicode-segmentation](https://crates.io/crates/unicode-segmentation) crate)

```rust
fn reverse(input: &str) -> String {
    let mut result = String::with_capacity(input.len());
    for gc in input.graphemes(true /*extended*/).rev() {
        result.push_str(gc)
    }
    result
}
```

I was told that the idiomatic way of doing it is a single expression

```rust
fn reverse(input: &str) -> String {
  input
      .graphemes(true /*extended*/)
      .rev()
      .collect::<Vec<&str>>()
      .concat()
}
```

While I really like it and want to use it, from a memory allocation point of view, would the former allocate less chunks than the latter?

I disassembled this with `cargo rustc --release -- --emit asm -C "llvm-args=-x86-asm-syntax=intel"` but it doesn't have source code interspersed, so I'm at a loss.

Comment: the "single expression" form should probably be a fold and not use a collect

Comment: Iterator implementation for `Graphemes` has `size_hint()`, which is being used by `String` for buffer size estimation in its `FromIterator` implementation, so I don't think there will be huge overhead due to use of `collect()`.

Comment: @DenysSéguret You mean like `.fold(String::with_capacity(input.len()), |result, gc| result + gc)` instead of `.collect::<Vec<&str>>().concat()`?

Comment: @DanilaKiver Thanks for commenting about `size_hint`; didn't know about it. Would the number of memory allocation requests/calls be one like in the first approach? I think for every grapheme-cluster there'll be one allocation due to the corresponding `Vec::push` and then a final allocation for `concat`. The reason I ask isn't specific to this toy example, I'm trying to understand how the second approach works.  Knowing it will be helpful in a larger project.

Comment: @legends2k yes, in order to avoid collecting into an intermediate vector. But at this point I'd need to do some benchmarks before I'd go as far as recommending it.

Comment: @legends2k, after re-reading `size_hint()` implementation I realized that it uses `1` as the _lower_ bound, and the code which reserves the space based on the hint relies on the _lower_ bound too (both for `String` and `Vec`), so it feels like there actually _will_ be problems with excessive allocations with this particular type (`Graphemes`).

Comment: Or the single expression form could have `.collect::<String>()` instead of `.collect::<Vec<&str>>().concat()`

Comment: @SomeGuy Or simply `.collect()` like in trentcl's answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your original code is fine and I do not recommend changing it.

The original version allocates once: inside `String::with_capacity`.

The second version allocates *at least* twice: first, it creates a `Vec<&str>` and grows it by `push`ing `&str`s onto it. Then, it counts the total size of all the `&str`s and creates a new `String` with the correct size. (The code for this is in [the `join_generic_copy` method in `str.rs`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.38.0/src/liballoc/str.rs).) This is bad for several reasons:

1. It allocates unnecessarily, obviously.
2. Grapheme clusters can be arbitrarily large, so the intermediate `Vec` can't be usefully sized in advance -- it just starts at size 1 and grows from there.
3. For typical strings, it allocates *way more space* than would actually be needed just to store the end result, because `&str` is usually 16 bytes in size while a UTF-8 grapheme cluster is typically much less than that.
4. It wastes time iterating over the intermediate `Vec` to get the final size where you could just take it from the original `&str`.

On top of all this, I wouldn't even consider this version idiomatic, because it `collect`s into a temporary `Vec` in order to iterate over it, instead of just `collect`ing the original iterator, as you had in an earlier version of your answer. This version fixes problem #3 and makes #4 irrelevant but doesn't satisfactorily address #2:

```
input.graphemes(true).rev().collect()
```

`collect` uses `FromIterator` for `String`, which will [try to use](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.38.0/src/liballoc/vec.rs#L1921) the lower bound of the `size_hint` from the `Iterator` implementation for `Graphemes`. However, as I mentioned earlier, extended grapheme clusters can be arbitrarily long, so the lower bound can't be any greater than 1. Worse, `&str`s may be empty, so `FromIterator<&str>` for `String` doesn't know *anything* about the size of the result in bytes. This code just creates an empty `String` and calls `push_str` on it repeatedly.

Which, to be clear, is not bad! `String` has a growth strategy that guarantees amortized O(1) insertion, so if you have mostly tiny strings that won't need to be reallocated often, or you don't believe the cost of allocation is a bottleneck, using `collect::<String>()` here may be justified if you find it more readable and easier to reason about.

Let's go back to your original code.

```
let mut result = String::with_capacity(input.len());
for gc in input.graphemes(true).rev() {
    result.push_str(gc);
}
```

This *is idiomatic*. `collect` is also idiomatic, but all `collect` does is basically the above, with a less accurate initial capacity. Since `collect` doesn't do what you want, it's not unidiomatic to write the code yourself.

There is a slightly more concise, iterator-y version that still makes only one allocation. Use the `extend` method, which is part of `Extend<&str>` for `String`:

```
fn reverse(input: &str) -> String {
    let mut result = String::with_capacity(input.len());
    result.extend(input.graphemes(true).rev());
    result
}
```

I have a vague feeling that `extend` is nicer, but both of these are perfectly idiomatic ways of writing the same code. You should not rewrite it to use `collect`, unless you feel that expresses the intent better *and* you don't care about the extra allocation.

### Related

- [Efficiency of flattening and collecting slices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58571612/efficiency-of-flattening-and-collecting-slices)

Comment: I'm a big fan of the `extend` version, and that's what I'd pick.

Comment: I think what I like about `extend` is that it fronts both the verb and the object being affected. You don't have to understand the whole line to see what side effect it has: it `extend`s `result`. Using `collect` or `fold` fronts `input`, so you see what's being iterated over first, then the form of iteration, and the "most important" bit -- allocating and filling the string -- is "buried" at the very end of the expression.

Comment: I would note that if the function is used *multiple times*, such as in a loop, it may be beneficial to provide a version which takes a `&mut String` out parameter. This may, in certain circumstances, allow reusing the buffer over and over.