# How can I have multiple iterators to the same data pertaining to a file?

Tags: file-io, rust, iterator

I have a file that I wish to read and filter the data into two different sets and determine the number of items in each set.

```rust
use std::io::{self, BufRead};

fn main() {
    let cursor = io::Cursor::new(b"pillow\nbrick\r\nphone");

    let lines = cursor.lines().map(|l| l.unwrap());

    let soft_count = lines.filter(|line| line.contains("pillow")).count();

    let hard_count = lines.filter(|line| !line.contains("pillow")).count();
}
```

- [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=001814f83935d7749b3f83de9603984a)
- [GitHub](https://gist.github.com/001814f83935d7749b3f83de9603984a)

However, the borrow checker gives me an error:

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `lines`
  --> src/main.rs:14:22
   |
8  |     let lines = cursor.lines().map(|l| l.unwrap());
   |         ----- move occurs because `lines` has type `std::iter::Map<std::io::Lines<std::io::Cursor<&[u8; 19]>>, [closure@src/main.rs:8:36: 8:50]>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
9  |     
10 |     let soft_count = lines
   |                      ----- value moved here
...
14 |     let hard_count = lines
   |                      ^^^^^ value used here after move
```

I tried getting around this using reference counting to allow multiple ownership:

```rust
use std::io::{self, BufRead};
use std::rc::Rc;

fn main() {
    let cursor = io::Cursor::new(b"pillow\nbrick\r\nphone");

    let lines = Rc::new(cursor.lines().map(|l| l.unwrap()));

    let soft_count = Rc::clone(&lines)
        .filter(|line| line.contains("pillow"))
        .count();

    let hard_count = Rc::clone(&lines)
        .filter(|line| !line.contains("pillow"))
        .count();
}
```

- [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ea1e913b6da58b46bc099d74d14c3a37)
- [Github](https://gist.github.com/ea1e913b6da58b46bc099d74d14c3a37)

I get a similar error message:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of an `Rc`
  --> src/main.rs:11:22
   |
11 |     let soft_count = Rc::clone(&lines)
   |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ move occurs because value has type `std::iter::Map<std::io::Lines<std::io::Cursor<&[u8; 19]>>, [closure@src/main.rs:9:44: 9:58]>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

error[E0507]: cannot move out of an `Rc`
  --> src/main.rs:15:22
   |
15 |     let hard_count = Rc::clone(&lines)
   |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ move occurs because value has type `std::iter::Map<std::io::Lines<std::io::Cursor<&[u8; 19]>>, [closure@src/main.rs:9:44: 9:58]>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. Instead, you will need to clone the iterator, or some building block of it. In this case, the highest thing you can clone is the `Cursor`:

```
use std::io::{self, BufRead};

fn main() {
    let cursor = io::Cursor::new(b"pillow\nbrick\r\nphone");

    let lines = cursor.clone().lines().map(|l| l.unwrap());
    let lines2 = cursor.lines().map(|l| l.unwrap());

    let soft_count = lines.filter(|line| line.contains("pillow")).count();

    let hard_count = lines2.filter(|line| !line.contains("pillow")).count();
}
```

For an actual `File`, you will need to use [`try_clone`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.File.html#method.try_clone) as it might fail. In either case, you will be referring to the same data twice and only the iterator information will be kept.

---

For your specific case, you don't need any of this. In fact, iterating over the data twice is inefficient. The simplest built-in thing you can do is to [`partition`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.partition) the iterator:

```
let (softs, hards): (Vec<_>, Vec<_>) = lines.partition(|line| line.contains("pillow"));

let soft_count = softs.len();
let hard_count = hards.len();
```

This is still a bit inefficient as you don't need the actual values. You could create your own type that implements `Extend` and discards the values:

```
#[derive(Debug, Default)]
struct Count(usize);

impl<T> std::iter::Extend<T> for Count {
    fn extend<I>(&mut self, iter: I)
    where
        I: IntoIterator,
    {
        self.0 += iter.into_iter().count();
    }
}
```

```
let (softs, hards): (Count, Count) = lines.partition(|line| line.contains("pillow"));

let soft_count = softs.0;
let hard_count = hards.0;
```

You could also just use a `for` loop or build something on top of `fold`:

```
let (soft_count, hard_count) = lines.fold((0, 0), |mut state, line| {
    if line.contains("pillow") {
        state.0 += 1;
    } else {
        state.1 += 1;
    }
    state
});
```

Comment: Thank you for such a thoughtful reply @Shepmaster. One more question. Suppose you did need to collect the sets, and they are not mutually exclusive, would your first recommendation be to copy the data and iterate twice? The reason I decided to determine the size of each set was so I could avoid fragmentation and allocate memory all at once. Does the collect method do this? Or does it request memory in single increments?

Comment: It's up to the implementor of `FromIterator` to decide if they will use the iterator's `size_hint` to preallocate memory. I generally assume that the implementation in the standard library is as smart as it can be based on the information it has. If you have info it doesn't, you might be able to assist, but I wouldn't worry about it until you have benchmarking in place to measure. Read [this wonderful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58612253/155423) for a concrete example.

Comment: Similar thoughts for double iteration versus copying the data. I think it's going to come down to how large the overlap is and how expensive copying is. Benchmarking is the best tool to know which is better for your data.